# Swift dictionary contains value but is not printed on the debugger console

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I am creating and printing values in a dictionary like this

```swift
let answersToSubmit = SubmitAnswerModel() //main model
let realm = try! Realm()
let savedExamResponse = realm.object(ofType: SavedExamResponse.self, forPrimaryKey: id)
answersToSubmit.uniqid = savedExamResponse?.uniqueId

var answerListToSubmit =  [QuestionAnswersToSubmit]()

for item in (savedExamResponse?.questionAnswerList)! {
    let answerToSubmit = QuestionAnswersToSubmit()
    answerToSubmit.qid =  item.questionId
    answerToSubmit.value.append(item.selectedOption)            
    answerListToSubmit.append(answerToSubmit)
    
}

answersToSubmit.answers = answerListToSubmit
print("length %s ",answersToSubmit.answers.count)//this is printing 100
print("answers to submit %s",answersToSubmit)//this is printing only the first part
```

The output is like this

```swift
length %s  100
answers to submit %s SubmitAnswerModel {
    uniqid = test-5cb2f6a2d81034.66536499;
    //the rest of the object needs to printed here, isn't it
}
```

So I am not quite sure if I have appended the array and put it in dictionary. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are printing an instance of SubmitAnswerModel, how is that class defined? Does it implement [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description)? Or do you only want to print the answers or value property? You might also want to explain where the dictionary is you mentioning, I can’t see any in the code.

Comment: I want to print everything that the instance of SubmitAnswerModel is holding and it doesn't implement CustomStringConvertible

Comment: You're printing it like a string, don't use that notation. Try simply print(answersToSubmit)

Comment: @Andrew21111 doing that will also print the same thing

Comment: Try to print the properties of the object in different print statements and see if they're printed

Comment: I am just curious how it prints that single property, anyway why not implement CustomStringConvertible then so you get everything you need when printing the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more comprehensive logging output try using the `dump()` function instead:

```
dump(answersToSubmit)
```

Which prints out a lot more information to the console.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the expected output in your for statement. I'm not sure why your trying to append, realm doesn't handle arrays as such. You might need to use realm Lists if you need to store arrays.

But from the code you have shown this should work.

```
 for item in (savedExamResponse?.questionAnswerList)! {
   let answerToSubmit = QuestionAnswersToSubmit()
   answerToSubmit.qid =  item.questionId
   answerToSubmit.value = item.selectedOption          
   answerListToSubmit = answerToSubmit
```

}